# How to prove that UFD implies normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, integral-extensions

How to prove that UFD implies normal? or is there is a reference containing this proof?

a ring $R$ is a normal ring if $R$ is an integral domain that is integrally closed in $\operatorname{frac}(R).$

And $R$ is integrally closed in a commutative ring $S$ iff the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ (int($R$)) equals $R$. And int($R$) consists of all $x \in S$ that is integral over R. And note that an element is integral over $R$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f(x) \in R[x]$ such that $f(x) = 0.$

Comment: What is "normal", if I may ask? Your question has no attention because you have not given details. Kindly provide some details or links.

Comment: Ok @TeresaLisbon I will edit my question.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Far better now. I expect replies in some time, although I am not very confident with the material so it may not come from me.

Comment: it is commutative algebra  @TeresaLisbon

Comment: No problem, there is an answer below now. Next time, kindly provide all possible details that you can, so that your question does not attract close votes for being too localized and self-serving. Your questions serve the community so imagine when you are asking a question that you need to be complete in asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is the same as in the case of integers and rationals.
Let $R$ be a UFD and $Q$ its field of fractions. Let $q = \frac{a}{b} \in Q$ be such that $q$ satisfies a monic polynomial over $R$.
WLOG, we may assume that $a$ and $b$ have no common prime factors. We show that $b$ is a unit and hence, $q \in R$.

Let $f(x) = x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n \in R[x]$ be a polynomial that $q$ satisfies. In other words, $f(q) = 0$. Multiplying this equation with $b^n$ gives
$$a^n + a_1ba^{n-1} + \cdots + a_nb^n = 0$$
or $$a^n = -b(\underbrace{\cdots}_{\in R}).$$
Thus, every prime factor of $b$ is also one of $a$. By hypothesis, there is no such prime. Thus, $b$ must be a unit.

Comment: Do you have a reference that contains this proof?

Comment: For instance Proposition 4.10 of Eisenbud's book "Commutative Algebra with a view toward Algebraic Geometry"